# iOS create file name list from asset catalog

Tags: ios, assets, asset-catalog

I am using asset catalog for emoji. The question is, how I could get all emoji file list from asset catalog to prevent hard coded array of file names?

I tried to create run script., but it's not working. creating txt file and put directory path only

```
for file in "./Images.xcassets/Smiles/"; do
echo $file >> ./Sparkle/smiles.txt
done
```

Maybe anyone could help me with this or other solution. Thanks

Comment: What's wrong with a hard-coded array?  You must have some idea about what emoji to use and so you need a table somewhere in the code, otherwise how do you use them at all?

Comment: Yes, I'll use them in collectionView

Comment: So how do you know which emoji to use?

Comment: from array I know their index

Comment: So that sounds like an array of filenames?

Comment: Sure, That what I want. The solution I have seen is create file then create array from file

Answer (score 0):

Ok, there is solution to create txt file with specific file list:

Run Script:

```
rm './Sparkle/smiles.txt'
for file in './YOURAPP/Resources/Images.xcassets/Smiles/smile_*'; do
filename=$(basename $file | cut -f 1 -d '.')
echo -e "$filename\n" > './YOURAPP/smiles.txt'
done
```